# Gitlab: team member project access levels

Tags: gitlab

GitLab offers the project access levels:

- "Guest"
- "Reporter"
- "Developer"
- "Master"

for "team members" co-operating with a specific project.

"Master" and "Guest" are self-explanatory, but the others aren't quite clear to me, in their extents as well as in their granularity.

What is the difference between these levels?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

2013: The [`project_security_spec.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/e8e9e0f771c34cf45e9c42f69de4da6b747f07e0/spec/models/project_security_spec.rb) test each profile capabilities, which are listed in [`ability.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/e8e9e0f771c34cf45e9c42f69de4da6b747f07e0/app/models/ability.rb#L59-L90):

(2017 GitLab 10.x: this would be more likely in [`app/policies/project_policy.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/e20d47aae3ca1d93b8e8acab4171248de536f9ec/app/policies/project_policy.rb#L64-L88))

See also, as noted in [jdhao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6064933/jdhao)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66669385/6309): "[Project members permissions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/permissions.html#project-members-permissions)"

Those rules are quite explicit:

```rb
def public_project_rules
  [
    :download_code,
    :fork_project,
    :read_project,
    :read_wiki,
    :read_issue,
    :read_milestone,
    :read_project_snippet,
    :read_team_member,
    :read_merge_request,
    :read_note,
    :write_issue,
    :write_note
  ]
end

def project_guest_rules
  [
    :read_project,
    :read_wiki,
    :read_issue,
    :read_milestone,
    :read_project_snippet,
    :read_team_member,
    :read_merge_request,
    :read_note,
    :write_project,
    :write_issue,
    :write_note
  ]
end

def project_report_rules
  project_guest_rules + [
    :download_code,
    :fork_project,
    :write_project_snippet
  ]
end

def project_dev_rules
  project_report_rules + [
    :write_merge_request,
    :write_wiki,
    :push_code
  ]
end
```

That means:

- a reporter is a guest who can also:

  - download code,
  - fork a project,
  - write project snippet
- a developer is a reporter who can also:

  - write merge request,
  - write wiki pages,
  - push code

---

Note: with [GitLab 15.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/05/22/gitlab-15-0-released/#users-with-the-reporter-role-can-manage-iterations-and-milestones) (May 2022):

> ### Users with the Reporter role can manage iterations and milestones
>
> We’ve changed the permissions necessary to create, edit, and delete milestones and iterations from the Developer to Reporter role.
>
> This change better reflects the typical day-to-day Reporter responsibilities of managing and tracking planning timeboxes.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/343889).

Comment: @Sven Excellent. But even more important, if those policies were to change/evolve, you now know *where* to look.

Comment: The link for `project_security_spec.rb` no longer works: `404 Not Found`

Comment: @ray Thank you. I have restored those (2013) commit links, and added the 2017 one.

Comment: Can these policies be changed on a gitlab installation?

Comment: @PhilLab Not sure. maybe that kind of script (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/27b84fd12f89607774bad941e3100a582d71ede4#2d52ce552f2d21beb86ec07b784cb47791f894cc_75_76) could be executed on setup? I don't know.

Answer (score 18):

These days, the access levels are well documented here: http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/permissions/permissions.html

Comment: Do you know if the `issues` module can have permissions assigned to it as well? I'd quite like to let some users only access `issues`, i.e. not the source code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the way permissions work for the `issues` module.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/permissions.html#project-members-permissions) from the gitlab official site shows the permissions for different levels of participants in the project.