# Gitlab: Issue with New Team Member

Tags: git, gitlab

I have created a new project on my Self hosted Git Server. This server use gitlab.

After created project, I added a new member as "Developer", But the developer is not able to push. I am master on the project and I can push on the server. What can be the issue?

Also, can you tell me what is the major difference between a master and a developer?

Answer (score 0):

As I explain in "[Gitlab: team member project access levels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17658437/6309)", a developer can push code.

So if the error persists, he or she must check his/her profile, making sure the proper ssh key has been registered, and that the ssh url to push to the gitlab server is correct.