# How to create a milestones in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm kind of new to Git and I'm using a GitLab repository to track my issue list. I wanted to create milestones but I can not find where. Are milestones and issue tracking part of the git itself and not of Gitlab?

EDIT: This is my milestones page screenshot:
There is no new Milestone button on it
[image]

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy What does a tag have to do with milestones? For example my stable version is a branch named 1.0. I develop against the master branch, I want to set some issues to be resolved by the time the version 1.1. I wanted to create a 1.1 milestone but I cant not create a 1.1 tag or 1.1 branch yet (because I'm still developing on the master branch).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Are milestones and issue tracking part of the git itself and not of Gitlab?

No, they are part of GitLab only, not git.

If that hasn't change from [issue 339](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/339), you have a "new milestone" button in the `Issues` section, tab '`Milestones`':

[image: http://cloud.github.com/downloads/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/milestones.png]

---

As the [OP Hoffmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3485/hoffmann) reports: **the presence of this button depends on your role** (or **[abilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17658437/6309)**).

As you can [see in `ability.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/models/ability.rb#L128-L143), only the ability '**`master`**' allows to create / manage milestones:

```
def project_master_rules
  project_dev_rules + [
    :push_code_to_protected_branches,
    :modify_issue,
    :modify_project_snippet,
    :modify_merge_request,
    :admin_issue,
    :admin_milestone,                   <=============
    :admin_project_snippet,
    :admin_team_member,
    :admin_merge_request,
    :admin_note,
    :admin_wiki,
    :admin_project
  ]
end
```

Comment: Ok it seems I have a version problem. I thought that since there was no New Milestone button on my screen I had to create them by git command-line.

But since milestones are not part of git itself it seems I have a bugged version of GitLab installed. Can you point me what version you are using. Also how can I find which version I am using? I was not the person who installed it.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my milestones screen. Maybe only the button is bugged? Can you give me a url example so I can try to access it directly?

Comment: @Hoffmann I don't have the latest version: the screenshot is from a 5.x version. I'll check tomorrow.

Comment: Ok I found out the problem, I was not a "master" user on the project. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: @Hoffmann Excellent. I have included that in the answer, with a referene to gitlab code, for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an external issue-tracker that is integrated into gitlab, you can't use milestones!